# How to avoid deadlock for this query?

Tags: mysql, transaction, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I am running a MySql 5.7 database and I have a query which results in a deadlock as it is running in multiple threads.

I am trying to figure out how to avoid this deadlock, but so far I haven't been able to do it. I even tried with:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

The query running looks like this

```
 UPDATE yjob_userrank target
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT userranks.id,
           @`row_number` := IF(@job_id = yjob_id, @row_number+1, 1) AS `row_number`,
           @job_id := yjob_id AS job_id
    FROM (
             SELECT yjob_userrank.id,
                    yjob_id,
                    rank_wo_date + users.`rank` as combined_rank,
                    is_match
             FROM yjob_userrank
                 JOIN users ON users.id = yjob_userrank.user_id
             WHERE yjob_id IN (1716, 1667)
         ) as userranks
    ORDER BY yjob_id, is_match DESC, combined_rank DESC
  ) source on target.id = source.id
SET relative_rank = `row_number`
```

And the schema is

```
create table yjob_userrank
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    user_id int unsigned not null,
    yjob_id int unsigned not null,
    rank_w_date decimal(5,2) default 0.00 not null,
    rank_wo_date decimal(5,2) default 0.00 not null,
    is_match tinyint unsigned not null,
    relative_rank smallint(6) null,
    created_at timestamp null,
    updated_at timestamp null,
    constraint yjob_userrank_yjob_id_user_id_unique
        unique (yjob_id, user_id)
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci;

create index yjob_userrank_user_id_index
    on yjob_userrank (user_id);

create index yjob_userrank_yjob_id_is_match_rank_wo_date_index
    on yjob_userrank (yjob_id, is_match, rank_wo_date);
```

This code is running in a laravel application and the method looks like this

```
private function calculateRelativeRanks(array $jobIds)
    {
        $jobIdsWhere = rtrim(str_repeat("?,", count($jobIds)), ',');

        $this->db->statement('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED');
        $this->db->transaction(function (ConnectionInterface $db) use ($jobIds, $jobIdsWhere) {
            $db->statement("
            UPDATE yjob_userrank target
              JOIN
              (
                SELECT userranks.id,
                       @`row_number` := IF(@job_id = yjob_id, @row_number+1, 1) AS `row_number`,
                       @job_id := yjob_id AS job_id
                FROM (
                         SELECT yjob_userrank.id,
                                yjob_id,
                                rank_wo_date + users.`rank` as combined_rank,
                                is_match
                         FROM yjob_userrank
                             JOIN users ON users.id = yjob_userrank.user_id
                         WHERE yjob_id IN ($jobIdsWhere)
                     ) as userranks
                ORDER BY yjob_id, is_match DESC, combined_rank DESC
              ) source on target.id = source.id
            SET relative_rank = `row_number`
        ", $jobIds);
        }, 3);
    }
```

The query only updates the field `relative_rank`, but it does not look at this field in the select part of it. I am okay with some data inconsistencies by reading uncommitted data, but even changing the isolation level to `READ UNCOMMITTED`, did not fix the deadlock.

By running `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` the block with `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` shows the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/olivernybroe/cbf9d2da0e04e4eaa902d5d01591e11e)

```
Explain log of the query
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type |     table     | partitions |  type  |                                                   possible_keys                                                    |                 key                  | key_len |              ref               | rows | filtered |         Extra         |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    |            | system |                                                                                                                    |                                      |         |                                |    1 |      100 | Using filesort        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>    |            | ALL    |                                                                                                                    |                                      |         |                                |  600 |      100 |                       |
|  3 | DERIVED     | yjob_userrank |            | range  | yjob_userrank_yjob_id_user_id_unique,yjob_userrank_user_id_index,yjob_userrank_yjob_id_is_match_rank_wo_date_index | yjob_userrank_yjob_id_user_id_unique |       4 |                                |  600 |      100 | Using index condition |
|  3 | DERIVED     | users         |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                            | PRIMARY                              |       4 | worksome.yjob_userrank.user_id |    1 |      100 |                       |
|  2 | DERIVED     |               |            |        |                                                                                                                    |                                      |         |                                |      |          | No tables used        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

As the database is MySql 5.7, I do not have Window functionality, so it is basically mirroring that functionality. If I had Window support, the query would look like this:

```
UPDATE yjob_userrank target
 JOIN (
     SELECT
        yjob_userrank.id,
        yjob_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (w) as `relative_rank`
    FROM yjob_userrank
         JOIN users ON users.id = yjob_userrank.user_id
    WHERE yjob_id IN (1716, 1667)
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY yjob_id ORDER BY yjob_id, is_match DESC, rank_wo_date + users.`rank` DESC)
     ) source on target.id = source.id
SET target.relative_rank = source.relative_rank
WHERE target.yjob_id IN (1716, 1667)
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I reduced the query to the following by suggestions from @Kondybas, this fixed my deadlock.

```
UPDATE yjob_userrank AS yjur
SET
    relative_rank = @`row_number` := IF(@job_id = yjob_id, @row_number+1, 1),
    yjob_id = @job_id := yjur.yjob_id
WHERE yjur.yjob_id IN (1716, 1667)
ORDER BY
 yjur.yjob_id
 , yjur.is_match DESC
 , yjur.rank_wo_date + (SELECT users.`rank` FROM users WHERE users.id = yjur.user_id) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is too complicated and involves too many nested loops for join proceeding. Also there are some portions of code having no effect at all. I think it can be simplified like that:

```
UPDATE yjob_userrank AS target
  JOIN ( SELECT yjob_userrank.id AS id
              , @job_id := yjob_id AS job_id
              , IF(@job_id = yjob_id, @row_number := @row_number+1, 1) AS row_number
              , rank_wo_date + users.rank AS combined_rank

           FROM yjob_userrank AS yjur
           JOIN users AS u ON u.id = yjur.user_id

          WHERE yjob_id IN (29,30 ...) -- only one list required
            AND @job_id = 0            -- not a NULL for correct comparison 
            AND @row_number = 0        -- not a NULL for correct comparison 

          ORDER BY yjob_id ASC
                 , is_match DESC
       ) AS source ON target.id = source.id

 ORDER BY source.yjob_id ASC
        , source.combined_rank DESC 

   SET relative_rank = source.row_number
```

I'm in doubt is that query is completely equivalent to your one but you can check if it produce the same set of rows if `UPDATE` is replaced by `SELECT` and final `SET` is commented out (just to transform a destructive query into non-destructive form). And you have to use the smaller set of `yjob_id`s for testing, indeed.

Comment: Something looks weird with your query. Your last `ORDER BY` is part of your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: So I used some of your methods and simplified the query a bit. However it did not fix my deadlocks. I was not able to remove the inner select join part, as the row number get's messed up then.
I Updated my questions to show the new query I created.

Comment: @OliverNybroe MySQL allows the syntax `UPDATE .. ORDER BY` in opposite say to the PostgreSQL. We can update rows in the certain order by dynamically calculated values of the user-defined variables.

Comment: Ah did not know that. However your query results in a `[HY000][1221] Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY` exception.

Comment: In the documentation it says `For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.`

Comment: I just made a select statement in the order by to solve that error, and it seems like it fixed everything. Do you have a better way of fixing it then an inner query in the order by?